# Silverstripe 4.11 / use custom class / ImageShortcodeProvider

Tags: silverstripe-4

In Silverstripe 4.11 CMS I try to add a custom class by default to all images set in tinymce - editor (HTMLEditorField).
I thought i could do this within SilverStripe\Assets\Shortcodes\ImageShortcodeProvider within  public static function handle_shortcode to change the output of ImageShortcodeProvider.

To use my own class i did a yml:

```
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector:
  SilverStripe\Assets\Shortcodes\ImageShortcodeProvider:
    class: CustomImageShortcodeProvider
```

I copied all the code from the original class but made my changes in public static function handle_shortcode.

```
.........
 // Build the HTML tag
        $attrs = array_merge(
            // Set overrideable defaults ('alt' must be present regardless of contents)
            //['src' => '', 'alt' => ''],
            ['src' => '', 'alt' => '', 'class' => ''],
            
            // Use all other shortcode arguments
            $args,
            // But enforce some values
            //['id' => '', 'src' => $src]
            ['id' => '', 'src' => $src, 'class' => 'jquery-image-fluid']
        );
............
```

unfortunately this has no effect. if i edit the original class it works as aspected.

Can you please tell me what i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcode parsers in Silverstripe framework are ultimately just callback - the class is just a convenient framing for it. The one you're trying to replace is registered as a callback [here](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-assets/blob/0512add1f69be9ad351a4dc29bd7eca94bda6e71/_config.php#L7-L9), which looks like this:

```php
use SilverStripe\View\Parsers\ShortcodeParser;
use SilverStripe\Assets\Shortcodes\ImageShortcodeProvider;

ShortcodeParser::get('default')->register('image', [ImageShortcodeProvider::class, 'handle_shortcode']);
```

In other words, you *cannot* replace shortcode providers using dependency injection. You can however register your *own* provider over the top of the original one by using the above code snippet, replacing the callback with your own inside your `_config.php` file. In your case this would probably be:

```php
use SilverStripe\View\Parsers\ShortcodeParser;

ShortcodeParser::get('default')->register('image', [CustomImageShortcodeProvider::class, 'handle_shortcode']);
```